# reduceByKey method not being found in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Attempting to run http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#a-standalone-app-in-scala from source.

This line:

```py
val wordCounts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
```

is throwing error

```
value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]
  val wordCounts = logData.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
```

`logData.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1))` returns a MappedRDD but I cannot find this type in http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/api/core/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

I'm running this code from Spark source so could be a classpath problem ? But required dependencies are on my classpath.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should import the implicit conversions from `SparkContext`:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```

They use the 'pimp up my library' pattern to add methods to RDD's of specific types.  If curious, see [SparkContext:1296](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1296)

Comment: Upvoted. Why didn't IntelliJ figure this out for me ?

Comment: this does not work for me. I am using  Eclipse and following is my  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: @AmrishPandey  You are using spark 2.X: you need to do `import org.apache.spark.SparkSession._`

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven on ScalaIDE I just solved the problem by updating the dependency from spark-streaming version 1.2 to version 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can find it in PairRDDFunctions class. PairRDDFunctions is a class contains extra functions available on RDDs of (key, value) pairs through an implicit conversion.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions