# reduceByKey after mapValues with parameterized type doesn't compile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, type-inference

When I call `RDD.mapValues(...).reduceByKey(...)` my code does not compile. But when I reverse the order, `RDD.reduceByKey(...).mapValues(...)`, the code *does* compile. The types appear to match up.

A complete minimal reproducing example is:

```
def test[E]() =
    new SparkContext().textFile("")
        .keyBy(_ ⇒ 0L)
        .mapValues(_.asInstanceOf[E])
        .reduceByKey((x, _) ⇒ x)
```

The compilation error is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943852/reducebykey-method-not-being-found-in-scala-spark) but its remedy doesn't help:

```
Test.scala:7: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, E)]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value reduceByKey'?
            .reduceByKey((x, _) ⇒ x)
```

This issue seems to more at the Scala level than Spark. Replacing the type parameter with Int works so it might be a problem with type inference. I am using Spark 2.2.0 with Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods such as `.reduceByKey` and `.mapValues` are members of `PairRDDFunctions` but you can call them because there is an implicit conversion from `RDD[(K, V)]`. But if you look closely at the definition of that conversion, you might spot the problem:

```
implicit def rddToPairRDDFunctions[K, V](rdd: RDD[(K, V)])
    (implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K] = null): PairRDDFunctions[K, V]
```

It requires a `ClassTag` instance for the `K` and `V` types. In your example, none is available for `E`, so the implicit conversion can't be applied, so it doesn't find the `reduceByKey` method. Try this:

```
def test[E]()(implicit et: ClassTag[E]) = ...
```

or the shorthand:

```
def test[E : ClassTag]() = ...
```