# reduceByKey/aggregateByKey alternative for a DStream[Class] Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There's already a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943852/reducebykey-method-not-being-found-in-scala-spark), but it is using Maven, and I'm using `sbt`. Moreover none of the solutions there worked for me

I'm using Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11.12 and IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1

My `build.sbt` looks like:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.groupon.sparklint" %% "sparklint-spark212" % "1.0.12" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.spark"),
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.2",
    "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.4.0",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.0",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.3.0",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-extensions" % "3.0.0"
)
```

Edit all over:

I will be receiving a stream of data from Kafka, which will be sent to the Spark Streaming context using:

```
val rawWeatherStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

From this, I want to create a stream of `RawWeatherData` objects. A sample output from the stream would look like:

(null,**725030:14732,2008,12,31**,11,0.6,-6.7,1001.7,80,6.2,8,**0.0**,0.0)

Things look all good, except that I need to remove the first `null` value to create the stream of `RawWeatherData` objects as the constructor cannot accept the first null value, but can accept all other values from the stream.

Just for clarity sakes, here's what `RawWeatherData` looks like (I cannot edit this):

```
case class RawWeatherData(
                           wsid: String,
                           year: Int,
                           month: Int,
                           day: Int,
                           hour: Int,
                           temperature: Double,
                           dewpoint: Double,
                           pressure: Double,
                           windDirection: Int,
                           windSpeed: Double,
                           skyCondition: Int,
                           skyConditionText: String,
                           oneHourPrecip: Double,
                           sixHourPrecip: Double) extends WeatherModel
```

To achieve that purpose, I send my stream into a function, which returns me the desired stream of `RawWeatherData` objects:

```
def ingestStream(rawWeatherStream: InputDStream[(String, String)]): DStream[RawWeatherData] = {
    rawWeatherStream.map(_._2.split(",")).map(RawWeatherData(_))
}
```

Now I am looking to insert this stream into a MySQL/DB2 database. From this `RawWeatherData` object (**725030:14732,2008,12,31**,11,0.6,-6.7,1001.7,80,6.2,8,**0.0**,0.0), the left highlighted bold part is the primary key, and the right bold part is the value that has to be reduced/aggregated.

So essentially I want my DStream to have key-value pairs of `([725030:14732,2008,12,31] , <summed up values for the key>)`

So after `ingestStream`, I try to perform this:

```
parsedWeatherStream.map { weather =>
        (weather.wsid, weather.year, weather.month, weather.day, weather.oneHourPrecip)
    }.saveToCassandra(CassandraKeyspace, CassandraTableDailyPrecip)
```

After the end of map, I try to write `.reduceByKey()`, but when I try that, the error says `Cannot resolve symbol`reduceByKey`. I'm not sure why this is happening as the function is available in the spark documentation.

PS. Right now `weather.oneHourPrecip` is set to `counter` in cassandra, so cassandra will automatically aggregate the value for me. But this will not be possible in other databases like DB2, hence I wanted an apt replacement, like `reduceByKey` in spark. Is there any way to proceed with such a case?

Comment: After the `map` operation, you have an `RDD[RawWeatherData]` which is not a pair (key-value) RDD. `reduceByKey` is only available for `PairRDD`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type of your stream is `DStream[RawWeatherData]` and `reduceByKey` is available only on streams of type `DStream[(K,V)]`, which is a stream of tuples consisting of key and value.

What you wanted to do is probably to use `mapValues` instead of `map`:

```
 val parsedWeatherStream: DStream[(String, RawWeatherData)] = rawWeatherStream
     .mapValues(_.split(","))
     .mapValues(RawWeatherData)
```

As you can see by type of `parsedWeatherStream` from the snippet above, if you'd use `mapValues`, you'd not discard your keys and you could use `reduceByKey`.

Comment: Hi, can you now look at the EDIT?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what your problem is, but maybe this will help: After `reduceByKey` you can just do `map(_._2)` and you will end up with the same stream as before.

Comment: The `RawWeatherData` constructor does not allow me to have the first value, that's why doing `_._2.split(",")` was quite important

Comment: Your solution does look good. But unfortunately I do need the `_._2.split(",")` part working somehow. I'm still working on it. No good progress though

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand what your is your problem currently. Could you edit your post and add more details?

Comment: I hope I am a little bit clear with the new edit. Please have a look